# given a finite group $G$, is it possible to determine the exact number of one-dimensional representations of $G$

Tags: representation-theory

Let's say $G$ has order $n$.  If this is all the information we have to go by, can we say conclusively what the number of one-dimensional representations of $GT$ is?  Or do we need more information?  Like the type of group?  In general, how would one go about finding this number?